# Periodic Worker в androidx

Tags: java, android, backgroundworker, androidx

#### androidx.work.Worker работает только при запущенном приложении. Если приложение завершить PeriodicWorkRequest перестает выполнять периодический запуск.

Нужно показывать уведомления через определенный интервал времени для этого использую PeriodicWorkRequest, при запущеном(даже свернутом) приложении оно работает как надо, он когда процесс умирает уведомлений больше нет.

класс воркера

```
import androidx.work.ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy;
import androidx.work.Operation;
import androidx.work.PeriodicWorkRequest;
import androidx.work.WorkManager;
import androidx.work.WorkerParameters;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Worker extends androidx.work.Worker {

    public static final String NOTIFICATION_TAG = "Notification";

    public Worker(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
       super(context, workerParams);
       Log.d(TAG, "NotificationWorkerInit");
    }

   @NonNull
   @Override
   public Result doWork() {
      Log.d(TAG, "doWork: START");
      Notification.showNotification(getApplicationContext());
      return Result.success();
   }


   public static void doNotifications(Context context, int quantityPerDay) {
      if (quantityPerDay > 0) {
          startNotifications(context, quantityPerDay);
      } else {
          stopNotifications(context);
      }
   }

   private static void startNotifications(Context context, int interval) {
       int minInterval = 1;
       PeriodicWorkRequest notificationsWorker = new PeriodicWorkRequest
              .Builder(Worker.class, interval, TimeUnit.SECONDS, minInterval, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
              .addTag(NOTIFICATION_TAG)
              .build();
       Log.d(TAG, "startNotificationsService: tag " + notificationsWorker.getTags());
       Log.d(TAG, "startNotificationsService: id  " + notificationsWorker.getId());

       WorkManager workManager = WorkManager.getInstance(context);
       Operation enqueue = workManager.enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(NOTIFICATION_TAG, 
            ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.REPLACE, notificationsWorker);
   }

   private static void stopNotifications(Context context) {
      WorkManager.getInstance(context).cancelAllWorkByTag(NOTIFICATION_TAG);
      Log.d(TAG, "stopNotifications: ");
   }
}
```

зависимости build.gradle (app)

```
dependencies {
  implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
  implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
  implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
  // implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0'
  implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.4.0'
  implementation 'com.github.judemanutd:autostarter:1.0.8'
  testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
  androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
  androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

manifest permission (service, receiver нету)

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
```

В Log нет ошибок, вот это пишет при закрытии приложения:

```
2020-08-09 18:28:31.772 1940-2694/system_process I/ActivityManager: Killing 5972:ego.emy.test/u0a85 (adj 900): remove task
2020-08-09 18:28:31.846 1940-2031/system_process W/InputDispatcher: channel 'e5ad803 ego.emy.test/ego.emy.test.MainActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
2020-08-09 18:28:31.846 1940-2031/system_process E/InputDispatcher: channel 'e5ad803 ego.emy.test/ego.emy.test.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
2020-08-09 18:28:31.851 1940-4150/system_process I/WindowManager: WIN DEATH: Window{e5ad803 u0 ego.emy.test/ego.emy.test.MainActivity}
2020-08-09 18:28:31.851 1940-4150/system_process W/InputDispatcher: Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel 'e5ad803 ego.emy.test/ego.emy.test.MainActivity (server)'
2020-08-09 18:28:31.856 1795-2041/? W/SurfaceFlinger: Attempting to destroy on removed layer: AppWindowToken{4ba78aa token=Token{5a74f95 ActivityRecord{634d34c u0 ego.emy.test/.MainActivity t9}}}#0
2020-08-09 18:28:32.285 1940-2261/system_process I/ActivityManager: Force stopping ego.emy.test appid=10085 user=0: from pid 6295
```

Раньше подобные задачи работали после обновления до androidx начались проблемы

Comment: Насколько я понимаю это поведение должно происходить только при Force stop приложения. Но к сожалению, на многих кастомных прошивках производителей девайсов, вместо обычного завершения вызывается force stop, например при простом закрытии из таск менеджера. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50682061/android-is-workmanager-running-when-app-is-closed/52605503#52605503